# Passing model to layout in MS MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

In views i`m passing model strongly typed way like this:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HomeModel>
```

And then just use it:

```
<%= Model.Greeting %>
```

How it would be possible to use strongly typed model in layout?

Without strongly typing i would probably add necessary data at controller factory, then use it through (LayoutModel)Viewdata["LayoutModel"]).Tralala, but i`m looking for better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create strongly typed property in your View:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected LayoutModel LayoutModel
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewData["LayoutModel"] as LayoutModel;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's a bit better, but still not what i`m looking for.

Comment: Haven't found anything better so far. :/